# Stopwatch loosing time in a browser using blazor and web assembly when browser put in background

Tags: c#, blazor, progressive-web-apps, blazor-webassembly

I have a fairly simple web assembly blazor app that I have created and released as open source to help coaches of high school track runners.   You can run multiple timers and take splits for multiple kids at the same time demo found at [track.tek-flow.com](https://track.tek-flow.com) .  If the browser is kept in the foreground and you don't let your screen go to sleep then the timer works as expected.   However if you close your screen and come back the StopWatch is behind on time.   It's fine that the page is paused but each StopWatch needs to keep an accurate time in the millisecond range.   Is there any way to keep the browser from stopping the StopWatch or to have it resume in Blazor?   I've not tried running it as a PWA but am not sure if that would run into the same issue.

Comment: Don't use a timer to count, increment or add time.  Check the hardware time at the start of a new lap (i.e. via the handler for a button click), and then in your periodic timer event, check the new hardware time.  Your elapsed time is just the delta of those.  Relying on events to fire when an app is minimized is going to end up in tears and frustration.

Comment: Use DateTime.Now to capture the start time. At any future point use `DateTime.Now - theCapturedStartTime` to work out the elapsed time, including when the stop/lap etc button is clicked

Comment: So I updated the app and switched to using Datetime.Utcnow.Ticks and it's better but I found with some testing the time still seemed to Drift off by 5-10 seconds after turning the browsers screen off for 10ish minutes.  Seems odd it would have a drift when using the Datetime.utcnow

Comment: How long are those laps that you'd turn the screen off for five minutes 

Comment: Create and Post a [mcve]. Ideally one that can exclude the device's clock as the source of the error. Also mind that you probably won't be able to get a precision down to the millisecond.

Comment: @MisterMagoo race times in a 1600 or 3200 are in the 5-14 minute range and not everyone using the timer would take a split each lap so

Comment: @Fildor human reaction time is about .2 seconds so millisecond accuracy isn't an issue but tenth of a second is.   The code is fairly simple but yeah I could create a smaller test but the issue is very tied to internal mechanisms of keeping time and the browser execution being paused.

Comment: Well, if you posted a [mre] you would get better answers quicker...

Comment: Agree on a repro,  a quick test here has no problem with sleep or hibernate